# Impute outliers to 2 sd below above the mean

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use outlier data, but setting anything that is above or below 2 standard deviations of the vector as 2 standard deviations above or below. The below code is not working.

```
Trimmean <- function(fd, var){
      con <- fd %>%
        mutate(var= ifelse(var > mean(var) + (sd(var, na.rm = TRUE)*2), mean(var) + sd(var, na.rm = TRUE)*2,
                             ifelse(var < mean(var)-(sd(var, na.rm = TRUE)*2),mean(var) + (sd(var, na.rm = TRUE)*2), var)))
      return(var)
    }
```

Comment: Please describe how the code isn't working for you. Are you getting errors? Is the output different from your expected output? Also, provide a [minimal, complete, & verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. Else we can't see what your dataset fd looks like.

Comment: The vector S_SM is coming up with NAs all over. There are no errors coming up.

Comment: Have you tried `sd(S_SM, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: Also, this is relevant only if the code works, but you are computing the `sd` 4 times, couldn't you compute it just once before the `filter` and then use that value throughout the `ifelse`?

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas thanks for your help, I have updated the code to be a function. I am receiving values, thank you!